# How do you stop `scan` after the first match of regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have:

```
bigtext = "I am happy. We are happy. He is happy too."
```

I want to scan the text and stop at the first occurrence of the word "happy".

I tried this:

```
bigtext.scan(/happy?/)
```

I used `?` to stop, but it continues to `scan`, and returns three occurrences of "happy".

Comment: One use of `?` is to make a regex non-greedy.  But, the regex /happy/ is not a greedy regex: the only thing it can match is "happy", which is a fixed length of five characters.  The regex will never match a string that is 6 characters long, nor a string that is 7 characters long, nor a string that is 8 characters long, etc., so it doesn't make any sense to try and make the regex non-greedy.  The things that are greedy in a regex are repetition characters, like `+` and `*`, so using `?` in conjunction with them makes sense.

Comment: Do you want this: `"Why is this happening to me, again and again?"[/happy?/]
 => "happ"`?

Comment: You can use `match` instead of `scan`.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*?happy
```

You can use this `m` or `multiline` mode.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/12

Answer (score 0):

`/happy?/` will match `"happ"` or `"happy"`; you are misusing the `?` (optional match) operator.

What you want is not `scan` (get all occurences), but `match` or `=~` or even `[]`.

```
bigtext =~ /happy/
# => 5
bigtext.match(/happy/)
# => #<MatchData "happy"> 
bigtext[/happy/]
# => "happy"
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want to know whether the string contains the word "happy", why not just use

```
find = "happy"
if bigtext.include?(find)
  return [find]
```

Otherwise you could use `match` if you need a regex operation to return an array

```
bigtext.match(/happy/).to_a #  returns ["happy"]
```

Comment: This is an example i think of, sorry for the bad example I used. What I wanted was for Ruby Regexp to stop scanning when it encounters the 1st instance that matches the regular expression, like a keyword.

Comment: In that case, the second example `match` should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use a block with `scan`, and place `break` after you have done whatever to be done within the block.

Without `break`:

```
bigtext.scan(/happy/) do
  p $`                                                                            #`
end
# >> "I am "
# >> "I am happy. We are "
# >> "I am happy. We are happy. He is "
```

With `break`:

```
bigtext.scan(/happy/) do
  p $`                                                                            #`
  break
end
# >> "I am "
```